# Calculating density within a shapefile

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, r-sp

I'm trying to calculate density within a shapefile, but I'm fairly confident I'm doing it wrong. The idea is to figure out which geographical regions there have been the most sales by density.

[Here is a link to the file that I use (testdata.shp)](https://github.com/gooponyagrinch/blob)

```
library(sf)

sample <- st_read("testdata.shp")

sample$area <- st_area(sample$geometry)

density_calc <-sample %>% st_buffer(0) %>% group_by(areas) %>% summarise(`Sales (density)` = sum(sales)/sum(area))
```

Here are the details of the shapefile:

```
Geometry set for 2106 features 
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -120.0065 ymin: 35.00184 xmax: -114.0396 ymax: 42.00221
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

I guess my issue is, I don't really know what is right and wrong, so I have no clue if I did it correctly.

Sorry if it's not the most extensive question, I just don't remember my high school geometry that well!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code except you don't need the zero-buffer and you don't strictly need the group_by/summarize because `areas` is unique in your data, so you end up will all groups of size 1. `sample$density = sample$sales/sample$area` will work just as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the `raster` package helps make this calculation very easy and just like working with a data.frame in `R`:

```
library(raster)
list.files(workDir)
test_shp <- shapefile(file.path(workDir, 'testdata.shp'))
names(test_shp)
#[1] "distrct"       "sbdstrc"       "terrtry"      
#[4] "region"        "turf"          "sales"        
#[7] "leads"         "cnvrsns"       "areas" 

sum(is.na(test_shp$sales)) #note that 346 polygons have no sales data

#get the area as square kilometers
test_shp$km2 <- area(test_shp) / 10000

#calc the sales density
test_shp$sales_density <- test_shp$sales / test_shp$km2

#calculate the 25th, 50th, and 75th percentile of all polygons
quartiles <- quantile(test_shp$sales_density, probs=c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), na.rm=TRUE) 

#plot the result, coloring by which percentile the sales density is for a given polygon 
plot(test_shp, col=ifelse(is.na(test_shp$sales_density), 'gray', ifelse(test_shp$sales_density >= quartiles[3], 'dark green', ifelse(test_shp$sales_density >= quartiles[2], 'light green', ifelse(test_shp$sales_density >= quartiles[1], 'yellow', 'red')))), border='transparent')  (eg. >75th, 50-75th, etc.)

#add the legend
legend('bottomleft', legend=c('Q4', 'Q3', 'Q2', 'Q1', 'No data'), pch=15, col=c('dark green', 'light green', 'yellow', 'red', 'gray'))
```

[image: Sales Density Result]

Comment: Don't do this. The `shapefile` function from the `raster` package returns an `sp` object, and these are deprecated in favour of `sf` objects from the `sf` package, like in the question. I don't see anything wrong with the code in the question.

Comment: @ Spacedman  I got the following error and warnings when testing the code in question: ```dist is assumed to be in decimal degrees (arc_degrees).
Error in group_by(., areas) : could not find function "group_by"
In addition: Warning message:
In st_buffer.sfc(st_geometry(x), dist, nQuadSegs, endCapStyle = endCapStyle,  :
  st_buffer does not correctly buffer longitude/latitude data```

Comment: @Spacedman I believe your comment is relevant only if you're relying on the ```tidyverse```  I found this quote from https://www.jessesadler.com/post/gis-with-r-intro/: "The sf package is meant to supersede sp, implementing ways to store spatial data in R that integrate with the tidyverse workflow of the packages developed by Hadley Wickham and others." This places your comment in better context.  Do you agree or could you provide more specifics?

Comment: The warning is because the user is doing a buffer of width zero which is not explained but is usually used to fix broken topology. The error is because you haven't done library(sf) or maybe dplyr to ge the group_by function. You don't need to "rely" on the tidyverse to use only `sf`.

Comment: Ok thanks @Spacedman, it was ```dplyr``` that was needed to run the questioner's code.  My sales density calculation lines up exactly with the questioner's calculation.  But I have provided a much simpler route to answer the question without the superfluous calls to all the ```dplyr``` and ```sf``` functions (they are all unnecessary to recreate the result).  I have also provided a simple way to visualize the result.  Because my result lines up exactly with what the ```sf``` package leads to, it seems there's no real reason to sound a warning to users of the ``raster`` package.

Comment: The warning is to users of the `sp` package. Your code pretty much all works with `sf` objects if you read the data in as an `sf` object.